# Generate URL Alias?? in PHP

Tags: php, url

I just saw this somewhere, and I'm interested on it, and can't seemed to find it anywhere or I just used the wrong words to search for.

Well I saw this link,

```
http://splur.gy/r/QqVYf/r/2tgNklHgmVK
```

and when I clicked it, I got redirected to other page which called

```
https://www.facebook.com/xxx.xxx?sk=app_xxxx
```

Anyone knows how this thing was made? or just a little hint to start off?

A help would be nice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are done with `RewriteRule`, a simple Google search willgive you mroe details.

In short, the URL will be broken down sorta like this: (Line 1, URL part, Line 2, PHP relative.

> http://splur.gy
> http://splur.gy/index.php
>
> r
> $_GET['var_1']
>
> QqVYf
> $_GET['var_2']
>
> r
> $_GET['var_3']
>
> 2tgNklHgmVK
> $_GET['var_4']

The `RewriteMod` will take the URL as setup in the above format, and pass the varialbes to a script. It is another way of posting variables in the URL.

As you see above: stackoverflow.com/posts/15182831, does not actually have a file named posts/15182831, it is simple used as a variable, passed to a script which queries that database, and spits out results based on what the script says.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have a server that will allow you to rewrite requests so you can redirect all requests to a single script. If you are running Apache, you would create an *.htaccess* file with something like this in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^r$ /redirect.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^r/(.*) /redirect.php?__q=/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Then if you go to http://yourdomain.com/r/234243/adsfsd, the request will be sent to the script /redirect.php and '234243/adsfsd' will be passed as the GET paramiter 'q'.

Then you would create a file called *redirect.php* that would process the request and then redirect the user. It might look somthing like this:

```
<?php

$redirection = process_to_determine_location_from_query( $_GET['q'] ); 

header( 'Location: {$redirection}' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called a redirect. You can do it in PHP with this code:

```
<?php
header('http://example.com');
```

Another thing that might have happened is that the link you saw was not the actual link you follow when you click. It's as simple as doing this:

`<a href="http://aha-gotcha.com">example.com</a>`

Comment: Just to clarify, that would be placed at the top of the page at `http://splur.gy/r/QqVYf/r/2tgNklHgmVK`.

Comment: Yeah, that generated link would be placed at the top of the page
http://splur.gy/r/QqVYf/r/2tgNklHgmVK
and when we go to that, it transfers into a new page. you could try though. Was it really header() function in php?