# How to create several URL aliases for a single page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'm using PHP and I've read about how to [create aliases](https://www.scorchsoft.com/blog/custom-page-url-aliases-php-htaccess/) and do a [rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182262/generate-url-alias-in-php) rule in [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

The thing is that I would rather like a functionality similar to the one that I do have in a Drupal site.

### For example:

The URL `example.com/info.php?id=18&type=article` should be accessible as:

**case 1:** `example.com/article/18`

and

**case 2:** `example.com/special-url-to-the-article`

I do understand the basics on how to create a specific alias for each article (case 2):

*I think that I should check the url with something like `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['type']` to look into it in a database that holds the alias and the other values, and if the alias exist form a new url with the id and type and send the user there.*

But how do I manage case 1, where I set the type of content and the content `id` programmatically?

I just need some guidance that could point me out to some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a similar rewrite and, right or wrong, this is basically what I do. In both cases, your `$_SERVER` array should have one or more of these values:

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /article/18/
[QUERY_STRING] => article/18/
[REDIRECT_URL] => /article/18/
[REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => article/18/
[SCRIPT_URL] => /article/18/
[REDIRECT_SCRIPT_URL] => /article/18/
```

For me, I would have the path of deliberate pages (like an "about us" page or whatever) saved in a database in order to be able to look it up using the path, but if not there, as in this case, then you deal with the path further:

```
# Assign one of the server paths that is most reliable
$path  = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
# Check if there is a path that matches a database path
$valid = $this->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `pages` WHERE `path` = ?",array($path))->getResults();
# If there is a page that is in the database, show that one
# Presumably this is what you mean by content and id programmically, ie.
# it's a pre-designated page, not an article that needs to be broken down
# but follows the same path pattern?
if($valid['count'] == 1) {
    # Go about doing normal stuff
    # Stop by using die(), exit, or if in function/method, return
    # Idea is to stop at this stage of the script if successful
}
else {
    # Explode the query
    $parts = array_filter(explode('/',$path));
    # Check if both parts exist
    if(isset($parts[0]) && isset($parts[1])) {
        # Assign type
        $type = $parts[0];
        # Assign ID
        $id   = $parts[1];
        # Fetch the results (you'll want to sanitize or match from an array the $type value to avoid injection)
        $page = $this->query("SELECT * FROM `{$type}` WHERE `ID` = ?",array($id))->getResults();
        # Check if page is valid and display
        # Stop by using die(), exit, or if in function/method, return
    }      
}

# Send a 404 header and display a not found
# Make the last thing happen show a 404 page by default
```

Anyway, this is basically what I do, but you can probably do a rewrite that will handle both scenarios from the `htaccess` file. I personally just have the one that funnels everything and I deal with the path and routing using PHP, then I don't have to create some user control to mess with editing the `htaccess` file if different scenarios are required down the line.

Comment: As you suggest in your last paragraph - this code does require a _front controller_ in your `.htaccess` file (ie. an internal rewrite to your PHP script). `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI'];` - This should probably be `REDIRECT_URL` (not `_URI`). It's not just a case of "the most reliable". These variables do contain different information. `REQUEST_URI` for example contains the full URL, including the query string, whereas `REDIRECT_URL` contains the URL-path only (and is only set after an internal rewrite).

Comment: @MrWhite Yeah sorry I pasted the wrong key name when I answered, should be REDIRECT_URL (or one of the others listed that provides consistent redirect paths).

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in `.htaccess`

1st case:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ info.php?id=$1
```

For second case:

```
RewriteRule your-desire-url$ yourpage.php
```